# iPhone unit testing for viewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a controller class in which i want to write the test case for the code which executed on the button click .In my testClass.m file i have following code from which i want to call the button from testClass.m . will this code work??

```
-(void)testcheckTheArrayForNull
 {
        viewController.temp=@"c";
        viewController.buttonCount=1;
        [viewController goButton:self];
        STAssertNotNil(viewController.setUpArray,@"set up Array is not nil");


}
```

By this code will my control transfer to goButton???

Answer (score 0):

I would say this *could* work, but you didn't provide code for goButton, setUpArray and I have no idea what temp or buttonCount do - so just guessing.

Comment: :ok forget the code in goButton. By using the [viewController goButton:self] can i access the code in goButton